# Finding third smallest number in a given set of numbers with least time complexity

Tags: javascript

Here's a working algorithm that finds the third smallest number in a given set of numbers.

I was looking for another solutions to the given requirement with less time complexity.

Here's the working code:

```js
Numbers = [3,2,55,-10,-55,5,3,2,1,-5,33,9,-1,4,5];
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function FindThirdSmallestNumber() {


for(var i=0;i<Numbers.length;i++) {

  if (Numbers[i] > Numbers[i+1]) {

    x = Numbers[i];
    y = Numbers[i+1];
      
      Numbers[i] = y; 
      Numbers[i+1] = x;

      i=-1;

  } else {
    //
  }

  

}

console.log(Numbers[2]);

}

FindThirdSmallestNumber();
```

Comment: What do you mean by less time complexity?

Comment: For the general case (kth smallest) you can use a max heap with a resulting time complexity of *O(n log k)*.

Comment: if you only need the 3rd smallest you can use 3 variables to keep track of the 3 smallest numbers and find the 3rd smallest in linear time..

Comment: `Numbers` is not a good variable name given it's similarity to the built–in *Number* object. Your approach seems to be a bubble sort, which is very inefficient and may require multiple passes to fully order the array (basically you keep iterating until nothing moves). I think the `i -= 1` is redundant, it just means the same to values are tested again on the next iteration.

Comment: Can you please explicitly state what the time complexity of your above algorithm is?

Comment: I'd bet a buck that if `Numbers`, `x`, and `y` were passed as parameters to the function - i.e. taken out of global scope - that it will be faster. I've seen significant slowness induced because the JS interpreter has to traverse layers of scope to find variable references.

Answer (score 1):

This one should be a lot simpler. Also not sure about this being any faster but in the most simple/obvious cases less code = better performance.

I just sort the array ascending and get the value based on index. So with this code you can get any place; lowest, second lowest, third lowest, etc as long as your index does not go out of range.

```js
const input = [3,2,55,-10,-55,5,3,2,1,-5,33,9,-1,4,5];
    

function getLowestByRank(data, rank) {
   data.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b });
        
   return data[rank - 1];
}
    
console.log(getLowestByRank(input, 3))
console.log(getLowestByRank(input, 2))
console.log(getLowestByRank(input, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is any faster but it's shorter:

```
//Use a custom sort function and pass it to the .sort() method
Numbers = Numbers.sort(function(x, y){ return x - y; });
if(Numbers.length > 2){
    //At this point, the 3rd item in the array should be the 3rd lowest
    console.log(Numbers[2]);
}else {
    console.log("There are not 3 numbers in the array.");
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to do the sort manually (or apply some other algorithm), not rely in the built–in sort (which was my first thought too).

Comment: @RobG Oh. Sorry. CoreDo, Is this not what you were looking for? If so, I can remove it.

Comment: Optimizing programmer time over program execution time is almost always the right call, unless you can prove otherwise using a profiler. That’s why I like this answer.

Comment: No need to remove it. The more the merrier. Plus, it really addresses the problem to some degree.

Comment: @AbanaClara Ok. Thank you. I'll leave it then, in case it helps in some way.

Comment: @VorpalSword—I disagree with that as a generalisation. Programmer time is a one–off, execution time is every single time code is executed, which might be millions of times per day. It doesn't take long to recover an extra few minutes, or even hours, of programmer time if your client is the one also paying for the users' time. ;-)

Comment: So.... profile it. A million hits per day- yeah let’s optimize that. A hit per month. Meh. Premature optimization is almost as bad as premature ejac*** you get the idea. Let’s let data drive us is all I’m saying

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have a *separate* sorted array of the three smallest numbers so far. Whenever you run across a number smaller than the 3rd smallest (the last in the sorted array), reassign that 3rd index to the new number, and sort it again:

```js
const numbers = [3, 2, 55, -10, -55, 5, 3, 2, 1, -5, 33, 9, -1, 4, 5];

const sortNumeric = (a, b) => a - b;
function FindThirdSmallestNumber(input) {
  const [smallestSoFar, numbers] = [input.slice(0, 3), input.slice(3)];
  smallestSoFar.sort(sortNumeric);
  numbers.forEach((num) => {
    if (num < smallestSoFar[2]) {
      smallestSoFar[2] = num;
      smallestSoFar.sort(sortNumeric);
    }
  });
  return smallestSoFar[2];
}

console.log(FindThirdSmallestNumber(numbers));
```

Note that implementations that `sort` the *whole array* (as other answers do) is `O(N log N)`, while `sort`ing *here* is only ever done on an array of size 3, which is significantly less complex (`O(N log 3)` I think, which is equivalent to `O(N)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.min` function to determine the minimum until you find your `X` smallest number:

```
Numbers = [3,2,55,-10,-55,5,3,2,1,-5,33,9,-1,4,5];

function FindSmallestNumber(arr, limit) {
   var min = '';
   for(var counter = 1; counter <= limit; counter ++) {
      min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(min), 1);
   }   
   console.log(min);
}

FindSmallestNumber(Numbers, 3); //3rd smallest number
```

Answer (score 0):

I think sorting the array is likely the fastest method, but perhaps you want avoid the built–in sort. An alternative is as Chris Li suggests: iterate over the values and just keep the 3 lowest, then return the highest of the three.

I assumed you want to avoid built-in methods, so this only uses some basic array methods and does everything else manually.

```js
// Avoid Math.max
function getMax(arr) {
  var max = -Infinity;
  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
  }
  return max;
}

// If data.length < 4, just returns largest value
// Iterates over data once
function get3rdSmallest(data) {

  // Helper to insert value in order
  // Expects arr to be length 3 or smaller
  function insertNum(arr, num) {
    if (!arr.length || num < arr[0]) {
      nums.unshift(num);
    } else if (num > arr[arr.length-1]) {
      arr.push(num);
    } else {
      arr[2] = arr[1];
      arr[1] = num;
    }
  }
  
  var num, nums = [];

  if (data.length < 4) {
    return getMax(data);
  }
  
  for (var i=0, iLen=data.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    num = data[i];
  
    // Insert first 3 values sorted
    if (nums.length < 3) {
      insertNum(nums, num);
      
    // If num is smaller than largest value in nums,
    // remove move largest and insert num
    } else if (num < nums[2]){
      nums.splice(-1);
      insertNum(nums, num);
    }
  }
  // Return highest (last) value in nums
  return nums[2];
}

var data = [3,2,55,-10,-55,5,3,2,1,-5,33,9,-1,4,5];

console.log(get3rdSmallest([-4,-22]));    // -4
console.log(get3rdSmallest([4,0,1,7,6])); //  4
console.log(get3rdSmallest(data));        // -5
```